# Как создать список списков со строковыми данными 'key:value'

Tags: python

Имеются 2 массива данных: keys = [(65.19999, 68.29999, 68.49998), (68.3,), (64.09999, 68.19999), (64.2, 64.39999, 64.59999, 68.39999), (60.8, 64.1), (60.99999, 64.3, 64.89999, 68.39999), (63.90001, 64.50001, 67.60001, 68.3), (63.90001, 65.2, 67.50001, 68.30001), (64.10001, 67.40001), (64.10001, 67.40001, 67.90001), (63.89999, 64.89999, 66.89999, 68.09999), (63.2, 63.3, 64.2, 64.8, 66.89999, 68.09999), (63.8, 64.2, 65.4), (61.5, 63.90001), (61.19999, 62.79999, 64.39999), (61.0, 61.8, 64.0, 64.3, 64.49999, 68.59999), (61.39999, 64.2, 64.6, 65.4), (60.0, 60.6, 64.0, 65.5), (60.5, 63.8), (60.00001, 63.90001, 64.90001, 65.10001), (61.1, 63.7, 64.4, 64.9), (61.7, 63.9, 65.3, 68.2), (63.5, 64.1, 64.6, 66.1, 68.5), (60.2, 62.8, 63.6, 64.10001, 67.40001), (60.1, 62.5, 63.5, 66.0), (60.0, 63.3, 63.89999, 64.99999, 67.19999), (60.2, 62.6, 63.0, 63.5, 65.0), (60.19999, 62.59999, 63.0, 63.5, 65.2), (60.6, 62.8, 63.7, 65.9, 67.1, 67.5, 68.9, 69.3), (61.99999, 63.89999, 65.7), (61.59999, 63.79999, 64.59999), (63.9, 66.1), (62.6, 64.10001, 65.2, 66.2), (62.60001, 63.80001, 64.8, 65.5), (60.99999, 62.09999, 62.39999, 63.79999, 64.29999, 64.69999, 65.29999), (61.0, 62.09999, 64.0), (62.0, 62.6, 63.7, 65.3, 65.7, 68.60001), (61.2, 63.6, 64.2, 64.7, 67.4), (60.1, 63.7, 64.6, 65.7), (62.10001, 63.30001, 64.3, 65.0, 65.3, 65.4, 66.1), (64.2, 65.50001), (60.1, 63.9, 65.1), (60.8, 62.1, 63.4, 63.9, 64.5, 65.8), (63.0, 63.90001, 65.3, 66.2, 69.3), (62.8, 63.3, 64.0, 65.1, 68.4, 68.6), (63.40001, 64.20001, 65.60001, 66.00002, 67.40002), (64.0, 64.5, 65.4, 67.1), (63.2, 64.3, 64.8, 65.2), (63.20001, 63.80001, 64.7, 66.9), (63.59999, 64.3, 66.89999), (60.7, 62.3, 63.6, 64.2, 66.0, 68.2), (61.19999, 62.89999, 63.59999, 64.3, 65.39999, 68.3), (60.0, 62.9, 64.1, 66.0, 66.4, 68.5), (61.0, 63.6), (61.40001, 63.40001, 64.2, 65.00001, 65.7, 66.7, 68.10001), (63.4, 64.4, 65.1, 65.6), (63.59999, 64.19999), (63.5, 64.2, 65.6), (60.2, 62.5, 63.2, 63.5, 66.39999), (63.2, 65.5, 65.9, 70.0), (62.3, 63.1, 63.5, 68.3), (63.19999, 63.79999, 65.09999, 68.59999), (63.1, 63.8, 65.10001), (63.2, 63.8, 65.10001, 65.3), (63.4,), (63.5, 69.8), (63.2, 64.8), (), (63.2,), ()]. Длина = 70. И

cls = [[16.0, 15.49193, 15.49193], [17.88854], [18.76166, 19.59592], [22.62742, 22.62742, 22.62742, 17.4356], [16.49242, 32.74141], [15.49193, 34.17601, 16.49242, 20.39608], [32.0, 15.49193, 18.76166, 17.4356], [35.32704, 19.18333, 17.88854, 19.59592], [27.71281, 16.0], [23.66432, 16.0, 15.49193], [24.65766, 16.97056, 16.97056, 15.49193], [17.4356, 17.4356, 33.4664, 21.16601, 15.49193, 20.0], [23.32381, 28.28427, 19.18333], [16.0, 33.7046], [16.0, 16.49242, 37.73592], [17.4356, 17.88854, 31.49603, 31.49603, 31.49603, 19.59592], [16.97056, 28.56571, 24.33105, 21.9089], [16.0, 16.0, 37.09447, 17.4356], [15.49193, 37.73592], [20.39608, 41.56922, 22.27106, 22.27106], [17.88854, 33.4664, 32.0, 18.76166], [15.49193, 37.52333, 19.59592, 16.97056], [23.32381, 29.12044, 31.74902, 16.49242, 17.88854], [17.88854, 16.0, 29.12044, 34.87119, 15.49193], [18.76166, 16.97056, 41.95235, 16.49242], [17.88854, 48.6621, 38.36665, 20.39608, 18.3303], [18.3303, 19.18333, 23.66432, 49.47727, 22.27106], [17.88854, 15.49193, 22.27106, 43.63485, 17.88854], [16.97056, 17.88854, 47.83304, 19.59592, 16.49242, 16.49242, 15.49193, 15.49193], [16.49242, 45.9565, 19.18333], [16.97056, 44.18144, 27.42262], [39.19184, 16.49242], [16.49242, 41.76123, 24.65766, 17.4356], [18.3303, 45.07771, 20.39608, 19.18333], [17.4356, 16.97056, 16.97056, 40.1995, 35.32704, 29.93326, 22.62742], [19.59592, 19.59592, 42.14262], [17.4356, 16.49242, 35.32704, 17.88854, 18.3303, 17.4356], [17.88854, 22.97825, 26.22975, 28.28427, 18.76166], [17.4356, 40.59557, 36.66061, 16.49242], [15.49193, 25.6125, 34.4093, 21.9089, 19.18333, 19.18333, 20.0], [33.7046, 16.49242], [16.49242, 33.7046, 17.88854], [17.88854, 17.88854, 16.0, 22.97825, 40.79216, 21.16601], [16.49242, 40.9878, 27.71281, 16.0, 16.49242], [16.97056, 18.76166, 40.1995, 23.66432, 16.49242, 16.49242], [20.39608, 32.49615, 21.16601, 17.88854, 16.49242], [30.98387, 29.93326, 21.9089, 17.88854], [16.49242, 31.49603, 27.12932, 19.18333], [20.39608, 33.94112, 23.32381, 17.88854], [42.33202, 29.12044, 17.4356], [16.49242, 16.49242, 34.87119, 35.32704, 21.16601, 18.76166], [17.4356, 19.59592, 36.22154, 26.533, 22.27106, 20.0], [18.3303, 20.0, 35.32704, 18.3303, 16.49242, 15.49193], [16.97056, 47.83304], [19.59592, 46.4758, 32.0, 20.39608, 16.49242, 17.88854, 17.88854], [45.60702, 22.27106, 18.76166, 18.3303], [40.59557, 24.33105], [37.73592, 24.33105, 16.0], [17.88854, 17.88854, 18.76166, 26.533, 18.76166], [30.72458, 17.88854, 15.49193, 16.49242], [17.88854, 28.56571, 27.71281, 15.49193], [29.93326, 20.39608, 16.49242, 15.49193], [28.56571, 20.0, 17.88854], [18.3303, 17.4356, 15.49193, 15.49193], [20.0], [18.76166, 17.88854], [20.78461, 17.4356], [], [15.49193], []]. Длина = 70

Необходимо сделать список списков той же размерности, что и исходные данные(Длина = 70),  внутри которых были б собраны данные по одному из keys и cls  в строковом виде, типа [['65.19999:16.0', '68.29999:15.49193', ' 68.49998:15.49193'], ['68.3:17.88854']... и т.д.].

Я пытался создать сначала словарь из keys:cls, потом из пар ключ:значение сделать строку, но получалось, строка из каждого элемента. 
Далее пытался сделать след.способом:

```
diz = []
    for i in keys:
        for j in cls:
            diz.append({k: v for (k, v) in zip(i, j)})
    fr = [[str(j[0]) + ':' + str(j[1]) for j in i.items()] for i in diz]
```

но получается 4900, вместо требуемой 70.

Сейчас пытаюсь так:

```
fn = []
    for i in keys:
        for j in i:
            for k in cls:
                for m in k:
                    fn.append(dict(zip(j, m)))
```

но выходит ошибка : TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration.
Как наиболее простым и правильным способом можно реализовать поставленную задачу?

Comment: *но получается 4900, вместо требуемой 70.* Ну дык append-ить надо только если индексы равны, а не всё подряд...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас получается произведение множеств, вам же нужно группировать их попарно

```py
result = [list(map('{}:{}'.format, a, b)) for a, b in zip(keys, cls)]
```

или вот так может будет понятнее

```py
result = [['{}:{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(keys, cls)]
```

Comment: Ок. Все получилось как надо. extm, Спасибо большое!))